# symfony4.1.3 The import Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture cannot be resolved

Tags: symfony4

I am learning Symfony 4.1.3.

I have created my demo project with composer:

```
composer -V: Composer version 1.7.1 2018-08-07 09:39:23
```

I have installed orm-fixtures:

```
composer require orm-fixture
    Using version ^3.0 for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.1.*"
    Nothing to install or update
    Generating autoload files
    ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
    ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
```

I have then created my fixture:

```
php bin/console make:fixtures
```

A file src/DataFixtures/ArticleFixtures.php has been created:

```
<?php
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;

class ArticleFixtures extends Fixture
{

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // $product = new Product();
        // $manager->persist($product);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

And then the line `use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;`is underlined in red with the following message:

```
The import Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture cannot be resolved
```

I am stuck with this error, I do not know how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Old topic but if this can help, i'd the same notice in Eclipse IDE with Symfony 5. However the namespace is right (check Fixture.php file under vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle) and the command  php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load worked with my fixture. I did a Project > clean command under Eclipse and the notice disappeared.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem while using Visual Studio Code and Symfony 5. Just close the IDE, open it again and the errors are gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).